# Prove $s_{i-1}t_i-t_{i-1}s_i=(-1)^i$ in the extended Euclidean algorithm.

Tags: euclidean-algorithm

We apply extended Euclidean algorithm for 
$$s_ia+t_ib=r_i$$
to find $\gcd(a,b)$ ($b>a$). The initial value is, $t_{-1}=1, t_0=0, s_{-1}=1,s_0=0$.

So, $s_{-1}t_{0}-t_{-1}s_{0}=(-1)^i$. Accroding to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_greatest_common_divisor#B%C3%A9zout's_identity_and_extended_GCD_algorithm), 
$$s_{i-1}t_i-t_{i-1}s_i=(-1)^i$$
will be satisfied. How to prove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a=bq+r$, then
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a \\ b
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
q & 1 \\
1 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
b \\ r
\end{bmatrix}$$
The matrix has determinant $-1$ and so does its inverse.

All steps in the extended Euclidean algorithm are like that.

Comment: I noticed the same method can be applied to prove $F_{n − 1} F_{n + 1} − F_n^2 = (− 1)^n$. Very clever. Thank you.

Comment: @ueir, yes, it's exactly the same reason because Euclidean division for Fibonacci numbers always gives $q=1$.